# Putting brackets when calling methods from laravel model

Tags: laravel, methods, routes, model, eloquent-relationship

My route looks like this:

```
    Route::get('/tags/post/{id}', function ($id){
    $post = Post::find($id);

    foreach ($post->tags as $tag) {
        return $tag;
    }
});
```

tags() methot in Post Model looks like this:

```
    public function tags() {
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Tag', 'taggable');
}
```

In this configuration my code will work, but when i put brackets after tags method in web.php my code returns null:

```
    Route::get('/tags/post/{id}', function ($id){
    $post = Post::find($id);

    foreach ($post->tags() as $tag) {
        return $tag;
    }
});
```

I need to know when do I put brackets after calling methods name?

Comment: `$post->tags` is a **Property**, and is equivalent to the **Method** call `$post->tags()->get()`. `$post->tags()` allows you to do extra queries, like `$post->tags()->where(...)`, then you finish it with a Closure, like `->get()` or `->first()`

Comment: That being said, putting `return $tag;` in that `foreach()` isn't doing anything... What do you want this Route to do? Typically you return a `view()`, a `response()` or a `redirect()`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I am currently watching https://www.udemy.com/course/php-with-laravel-for-beginners-become-a-master-in-laravel/ this couse, i am absulute laravel beginner. I just needed to know when to put brackets. Thanks for very quick reply.

Comment: Ah gotcha! Yeah, in Laravel, specifically with Models, using or omitting `()` makes a _huge_ difference. Laravel "magically" converts relationship Methods like `public function tags()` to Properties for shortcut access, with the equivalency noted above. If you're ever unsure, use `dd()`, `dd($post->tags)` should show you a Collection, while `dd($post->tags())` should show you a `Builder` instance, etc. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$post->tags is a Property, and is equivalent to the Method call $post->tags()->get(). $post->tags() allows you to do extra queries, like $post->tags()->where(...), then you finish it with a Closure, like ->get() or ->first() –
Tim Lewis

Yeah, in Laravel, specifically with Models, using or omitting () makes a huge difference. Laravel "magically" converts relationship Methods like public function tags() to Properties for shortcut access, with the equivalency noted above. If you're ever unsure, use dd(), dd($post->tags) should show you a Collection, while dd($post->tags()) should show you a Builder instance, etc. Happy coding! –
Tim Lewis